# Pcie 1x video card

Tags: pci-express

I have a radeon 6750.  I'd like to add another video card for more monitors.  I have an open pcie 1x slot.  Do I have to get another card from the 6700 series, or will any ole pcie 1x card work?  Does such an animal( 6700 1x ) exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply wanting to add another monitor, then any AMD/ATI PCI-E card should be fine.

It does not matter if it is a x16 card, it will operate at a lower bandwidth which is fine if you are just using it for general desktop usage.